# I'm getting errors called "Public isn't a valid Modifier"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

My code is stating that "the modifier public is not valid for this item". I have 5 of these errors, and a sixth that states "the name `OutputStory` does not exist in the current context". I hope you could help me, many thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] StoryState startingStory;
    [SerializeField] StoryState specialEnding;
    string storyText;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI storyTextBox;
    StoryState currentStory;
    [SerializeField] Image myStoryImage;
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem endingParticles;
    bool check = false;
    [SerializeField] GameObject amongus;
    int rand;
    float x;
    float y;



    private void Start()
    {
        endingParticles.Stop();
        currentStory = startingStory;
        OutputStory();



    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (check == true)
        {
            if (rand == 1)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale += new Vector3(x, y, y + x) * Time.deltaTime;

            }
            else if (rand == 2)
            {
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y, x * y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 3)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale += new Vector3(x, y, x / y) * Time.deltaTime;
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y, x - y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 4)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale += new Vector3(x * x, y, x / y) * Time.deltaTime;
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y / y, x - y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 5)
            {
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y, x - y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 6)
            {
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y, x / y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 6)
            {
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y * y, x * y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 7)
            {
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y / y, x * y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 8)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(x / x, y * x, y + x) * Time.deltaTime;

            }
            else if (rand == 9)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(y * x, y / x, y - x) * Time.deltaTime;

            }
            else if (rand == 10)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(y * x, y / x, y - x) * Time.deltaTime;
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y / y, x * y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 11)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale += new Vector3(x, y, x * y) * Time.deltaTime;
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y, x + y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (rand == 12)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale += new Vector3(x, y, x * y) * Time.deltaTime;
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y, x - y) * Time.deltaTime);

            }
            else if (rand == 13)
            {
                amongus.transform.localScale += new Vector3(x, y, x * y) * Time.deltaTime;
                amongus.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(x, y, x - y) * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }

        void OutputStory()
        {
            storyText = currentStory.GetStoryText();
            storyTextBox.text = storyText;
            myStoryImage.sprite = currentStory.GetSceneImage();
        }
        void ManageStory(int option)
        {
            var nextOptions = currentStory.GetStoryOption();
            if (option > nextOptions.Length - 1)
            {
                Debug.Log("Test");
                storyText = "That is not an option";
                Invoke("OutputStory", 1);
            }
            else
            {
                currentStory = nextOptions[option];
                OutputStory();
            }
        }
        public void OnOpt1()
        {
            ManageStory((int)0);
        }
        public void OnOpt2()
        {
            ManageStory((int)1);
        }
        public void OnOp3()
        {
            ManageStory((int)2);
        }
        public void OnAMUNGUS()
        {
            Debug.Log("Amungus");
            if (currentStory.name == ("E9 - Reported"))
            {
                currentStory = specialEnding;
                OutputStory();
                endingParticles.Play();
                check = true;
                rand = (int)Random.Range(1f, 13f);
                Debug.Log(rand);
                x = Random.Range(-100f, 100f);
                y = Random.Range(-100f, 100f);
            }
        }

        public void OnExitPress()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
        }
    } }
```

Comment: One of your brackets is misplaced. You are declaring methods inside the Update method

Comment: If you format your code properly, errors like this usually stand out.

Comment: I should probably format better in the future. Where is the bracket misplaced?